# Enable type quick info with // ^?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

[ts-plaground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=8&ts=4.7.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoF4BEwHFQKAPS6kID0B+IA) has feature where you can display the quickinfo of a type using "// ^?". I want to enable this feature in vs-code but I weren't able to find the settings for this. Do you have any idea to make this work?

I want to enable this feature in vs-code but I weren't able to find the settings for this. Do you have any idea to make this work?

Comment: Yes, it's called [Two Slash Queries](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Orta.vscode-twoslash-queries) and it's made by one of the contributors to TypeScript, [orta](https://github.com/orta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment of [vera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18244921/vera). The plugin is called [Two Slash Queries](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Orta.vscode-twoslash-queries). Thanks a lot :)